# convert a timestamp set as a numeric value like "1476854074803" to a date

Tags: date, converters

I have a log file where events are timestamped as "1476854074803". I'd like to convert it to date and time of the day. I suspect that it's the numeric value representing the date/time  with "1970-01-01" as origin.

Thank you for your help. Couldn't find any answer...
Frederic

Comment: What is your OS/shell?

Comment: I'm working with Version 0.98.1091 of RStudio under windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I found:
as.POSIXct(1476854074, origin = "1970-01-01")

gives me: "2016-10-19 07:14:34 CEST"

so you scrap the 3 last digits  --> 1476854074 instead of 1476854074803

would give: "48769-08-23 13:00:03 CEST"  (won't be there to check...)